# changing spacing of q-select options in Quasar

Tags: quasar

Apologies if this is an ignorant question
I want the drop down options in q-select in quasar to be closer together vertically
I've seen a previous post about making the text larger that suggests using
"popup-content-class and/or popup-content-style", and whilst I can change the text size using these as suggested, I don't know how to just change the vertical spacing (padding/margin?)
Again, I realise this is my lack of knowledge, but I don't seem to be able to find anything on how to do this